# Black Standard Deviation in QuantLibXL

Tags: volatility, quantlib, implied, black

I was having a doubt about a fucntion in the QuantLib add-on for excel.
What is the formula for the function:  `qlBlackFormulaImpliedStdDev(...)`
I know that there are different methods for finding implieds (such as the Newton-Raphson).
I mean, if you would write it down as a formula, how should it be??

Comment: Bisection method

Comment: Thank you. I have searched but from where did you read it??